# Disable/Enable Submit Button When clicking on CheckBox using Jinja2 Templating

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I have the following template to delete an account :

[image]

To Delete this account first you need to tick the checkbox then Button Delete will be enabled, this is what to be done

My question is it possible to perform this using jinja2 Templating ? if yes how ?

Thanks.
/K

Comment: Yes, it is possible using javascript.

Comment: do you have an example ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want your checkbox to be required, right?
That's [simple](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-checkbox-required/): use `<input required>` if you only want to notify the user on clicking the button without checked box.
If you want to disable the button entirely, you will need to write some js.

Comment: How to implement it using jinja2 ?